# matplotlib change arrow color

Tags: matplotlib, colors, arrow-functions

First, I'm new to matplotlib (pyplot).
I have a raster plot of arrows (lines) at varying lengths and points on the graph.  What I'm trying to do is override the fc and ec colors after a mouse click event is received.  Code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
plt.arrow(1, 3, 4, 0, head_width=None, head_length=None)
plt.arrow(3, 2, 1, 0, head_width=None, head_length=None)
plt.arrow(5, 8, 2, 0, head_width=None, head_length=None)
plt.arrow(2, 7, 6, 0, head_width=None, head_length=None)
plt.arrow(9, 9, 8, 0, head_width=None, head_length=None)
plt.arrow(129, 42, 30, 0, head_width=None, head_length=None, fc="b", ec="b")
plt.axis([0, 200, 50, 0])
plt.title("Time")
plt.xlabel("length of interval")
plt.ylabel("Time")

def onClick(event):
    print("xdata:", event.xdata, " ydata:", event.ydata)
    plt.arrow(129, 42, 30, 0, head_width=None, head_length=None,\
    fc="r", ec="r")
    plt.plot()

fig.canvas.mpl_connect("button_press_event", onClick)

plt.show()
```

Here are the results

[image: image of results]

Comment: When you set head width and length to none, this effectively does not produce any arrow, but a line, right? So would you like to update lines instead of arrows?

Comment: A line is what I'm trying to produce.  Start point (x,y) where the delta in y is always zero (0) and x is time time interval (from start to finish).  The idea of the onClick (mouse event) is that when a "line" is selected change the color. Now there is more logic needed to find the exact point selected (don't need help for that).  And I simply chose a previously defined line (arrow) to see if the results could be accomplished.

Comment: I'd suggest, remove all `arrow`s from your code and use lines. Then use a `pick_event`. Once you're stuck [edit] the question with your actual problem.